# Как присвоить http:// при вводе сайта в консоли

Tags: c#, ip

Для поиска ip адрессов определенного сайта я использовал:

```
Console.Write("Впишите имя сайта для поиска: ");
        Uri uri = new Uri(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(uri.Host + "\r\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Список IP Адрессов" + "\r\n");
        IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.DnsSafeHost);
       // Console.WriteLine(ip);
        //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        foreach (var addr in ip.AddressList)
            Console.WriteLine(addr);
        Console.Read();
```

Если написать сайт без `http://` + `https`

Выскакивает табличка:
**Недопустимый URI: Невозможно определить формат URI.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для резольва доменных имён не нужен `Uri`.

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Console.ReadLine());
foreach (var addr in hostEntry.AddressList)
  Console.WriteLine(addr);
```

Или даже

```
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Console.ReadLine());
foreach (IPAddress addr in addresslist)
   Console.WriteLine(addr.ToString());
```

---

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите имя хоста:");
while (true) {
  try {
    IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Console.ReadLine());
    foreach (IPAddress addr in addresslist)
       Console.WriteLine(addr.ToString());
    break;
  } catch (SocketException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Попробуйте ещё раз:");
  }
}
```

Comment: А как возвратиться к новой строке если сайт недопустим, или не доступен?

Comment: Завернуть в цикл, пока массив пуст. Также ловить SocketException

Comment: [Список исключений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Хорошо, только вот при следующем вводе окно закрывается использовал `Console.Read();`

Comment: Ну, это тонкости интерфейса, к вопросу мало относятся)

Comment: Удалите break, это оставит вас внутри цикла. Что значит возвратиться назад? Я не вполне понимаю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53099/discussion-between-artes-and-vp-arth).

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как-то по обычному:

```
 string MyString = "http://";
        Uri uri = new Uri(MyString + Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Что если во вводе уже содержится `http://` или `https://`? Нужно проверять)

Comment: @vp_arth, Ну мне нужно чтобы я мог вводить напрямую `google.com`, без `http://www.`